# Braintree Sub-Merchant Display Income

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree

Currently integrating Braintree's marketplace service with my Rails 4 app.

Wondering if there is any way to display current earnings to a sub-merchant (including what is in escrow and what has been deposited into their bank account).

I realize I can handle this just using the rails side of things, but making a call to their api to get this info seems more efficient and definitely better for congruency b/t braintree and my app.

Having trouble finding anything regarding this in the documentation. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>I work for Braintree.</sub>

There is currently no way to use the Braintree API to return current earnings for a submerchant.

If you have any additional questions, feel free to reach out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).